# Where to place drush in MAMP

Tags: drush

I placed drush in MAMP folder outside of htdocs folder and downloaded drupal successfully but obviously to wrong folder. Where should drush be placed to have it work with drupal folder in htdocs folder?

Comment: It may not be obvious for someone unfamiliar with the command line, but this is an osx question. Drush doesn't care where it's installed.

Comment: Well, I feel it is more of a MAMP question because they package the free vs with pro it is hard to tell which version of php to point the alias to and there are currently three in php folder.

Comment: Potentially it is a MAMP question, but that still leaves it off-topic for the site. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the drush qd command and add the --root parameter. You can use it to download the Drupal installation into /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

Comment: Actually, I ended up going for mysql instead of lite option in above answer- so placed drush in mamp folder but it is giving me an error and this link http://drupal.org/node/1428638 when I tried the following code from that link it didn't work so still trying to break fee of jail shell.

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: The drush command 'up' could not be executed.                        [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
 *  The socket file may be
wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell.

Comment: It sounds like you are running drush on a folder that has no Drupal installation (Note that I'm saying installation that goes through the actual install process, not just putting the Drupal files there). Use the 'qd' command to install.

Comment: Thanks , radj will do if can't figure this out but in meantime I will persist. I have three versions of php and I need to set path correctly but not sure which one pertains to the free copy of MAMP.

Comment: Sounds complicated. Good luck! :)